# PHP html mysql update multiple checkbox in where condition

Tags: php, mysql, html

i want to update my table with multiple where condition with for example 
 table name is zz

```
    +----+------+------+
    | id | X1   | X2   |
    +----+------+------+
    |  1 |  xya | Abc  |
    |  2 |  yaz | xyz  | 
    |  3 |  wee | xsc  | 
    |  4 |  fss | xcs  |
    |  5 |   eer| XXX  |
    +----+------+------+
```

my query is like this

```
UPDATE `zz` SET `x1` = 'hi'  WHERE `zz.`id` = 1 and zz.`id` = 2 and zz.`id` = 3
```

And  'ID' selected through check box Like this

```
<html>

<head>
 <script>
 function getcheckboxes() {
var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var checkboxes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) 
{
    var node = node_list[i];
    if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') 
{
        checkboxes.push(node);
    }
} 
return checkboxes;
 }
  function toggle(source) {
   checkboxes = getcheckboxes();
   for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) 
  {
checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
 }
 </script>
</head>

  <body>
  <form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo1" value="1"> 1<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo2" value="2"> 2<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo3" value="3"> 3<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo4" value="4"> 4<br/>

  <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```

so by this i like to select some ID through check box

Comment: Where is your PHP code? Show us what you have tried and maybe we can help you. Also, shouldn't those be OR conditions in the update statement, instead of AND?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL IN Operator
The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.
The IN operator is a shorthand for multiple OR conditions.

`UPDATE ***
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);`

You can check this out. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following jQuery ajax code

```
 $("form").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var arr=[];
                $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                    arr.push($(this).val());
                 });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
                        data: {data:arr},
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert(result);
                        }
                    });

                return false;
            });
```

Add this code at PHP side:

```
<?php

$updateWhere=$_POST['data'];
$where=array();
foreach($updateWhere as $value){
    $where[] = " `zz.`id`=".$value;
}
$sql="UPDATE `zz` SET `x1` = 'hi' "; 
$sql.=' WHERE '. implode(' AND ', $where);
echo $sql; die;
```